# How to read numbers form columns in CVS files? (Python)

Tags: python, csv

How can I read a column from a CSV file and turn all of it into a string, and then add it?

```
import csv

print("HI!, Welcome to spreadsheet reader protype")
fileNameLocator = input("Search file: ") + ".csv"
fileName = open(fileNameLocator)
fileReader = csv.reader(fileName)

# price column
next(fileReader)
for line in fileReader:
    print(line[11])
```

I have this block of code that prints the desired columns I want from a file, and it gives the numbers vertically as a list, but these numbers are a string, how can I turn them into floats (they are decimals) and then add this numbers(20 or so).

Comment: Convert your list of strings to float as per explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614236/in-python-how-do-i-convert-all-of-the-items-in-a-list-to-floats?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: can you add sample of your file ?

Comment: Also have a look at pandas, as provide wide range of functionality to manage csv files, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining Data Type during csv file import based on column index in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958349/defining-data-type-during-csv-file-import-based-on-column-index-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, to cast something as a `float`, you pass it into the `float` constructor.

Example:

```py
number_string = '1.234'
print(type(number_string))
number = float(number_string)
print(type(number))
```

In your case, it would be something like `number = float(line[11])`.